# DllImport can't find dll even though dll is in same folder as executable

Tags: .net, f#, llvm, dllimport, llvm-fs

I'm trying to use the [llvm-fs](https://github.com/keithshep/llvm-fs) project, which provides llvm bindings for F#. I have compiled the `LLVM-3.1.dll` file with `--enable-shared` and it now resides in same directory as my compiled executable (I checked with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`). The `DllImport` in llvm-fs looks like:

```
[<DllImport(
    "LLVM-3.1.dll",
    EntryPoint="LLVMModuleCreateWithName",
    CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]
extern void* (* LLVMModuleRef *) moduleCreateWithNameNative(string ModuleID)
```

Yet when I run my application it errors with:

```
Unable to load DLL 'LLVM-3.1.dll': The specified module could not be found.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

How do I get the DLL to be loaded? For reference, [here's the exact DLL I'm trying to load](https://github.com/CRogers/BasicCompiler/blob/05e0c6dce687f58b925e9e4425ec019bff2ad88a/lib/llvm-3.1/LLVM-3.1.dll).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This:

> "The specified module could not be found"

can point to some library, which `LLVM-3.1.dll` depends from, not the `LLVM-3.1.dll` itself.

Comment: just saved me hours

Comment: If you have the source code of the dll (in general case) make sure you compile it with `/MT` instead of `/MD` (`/MTd` instead of `/MDd` in case of debug build).
This will use static linking of runtime libraries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=vs-2019

Comment: Any hint how to pinpoint that some library ? Dependency Walker just freezes (

Answer (score 12):

When DLL or EXE fail to load as in this case [Depends.exe](http://dependencywalker.com/) is very handy - it display the complete EXE/DLL dependency tree, highlighting what cannot be loaded or it is missing.